# Element not hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below Javascript code, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#answer').hide(); //hiding the element
    $('#questionOne').click(function () {
        $('#answer').show();
```

However, the element does not get hidden on load. My HTML is this:

```
<p id="answer">All requests of this nature are required to be submitted via our website www.mufoundation.org/charityrequests. Due to the volume of requests we receive, we require at least 6 weeks notice prior to your event. If your event does not fall within this timescale unfortunately, we will not be able to help.</p>
```

I cannot seem to hide the paragraph answer element. How can I do this?

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always going to be hiding it on load would it not be better practice to not hide it on load and rather attach a CSS class that sets it to hidden? It's extremely simple to do just change your code to do this.

Create a CSS Class called hide

```
.hide{
 display : none;
}
```

Add the class below.

```
<p id="answer" class="hide">All requests of this nature are required to be submitted via our website www.mufoundation.org/charityrequests. Due to the volume of requests we receive, we require at least 6 weeks notice prior to your event. If your event does not fall within this timescale unfortunately, we will not be able to help.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is literally all the jQuery you have then you have forgotten to add `}); });` at the end of the script. So your code should look like this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#answer').hide(); 
    $('#questionOne').click(function () { 
        $('#answer').show();
    });
});
```

if that doesn't fix your problem, are you sure you're including the appropriate jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

If you posted the right code, then it's the wrong syntax.

### Right code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#answer').hide(); //hiding the element
$('#questionOne').click(function () {
    $('#answer').show();
 });  });<-- you forgot the clossing brackets
```

I hope it was that! Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class to hide the stuff instead of doing it in onload:

HTML:

```
<p class="hide">zyz</p>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
 }
```

And then, use the following to show it using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#questionOne').click(function () {
        $('#answer').show();
    });
});
```